# Angular 2 [routerLink] navigates but doesn't update the url

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes

My Link

```
    <a [routerLink]="['/login']">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Login
    </a>
```

My Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: UserRegisterComponent },
  { path: 'auctions', component: AuctionListComponent },
  { path: 'auction/:id', canActivate: [ AuctionDetailGuard ], component: AuctionDetailComponent },
  { path: 'supplier/:id', component: SupplierDetailComponent }
];
```

the routerlinks that navigates to auctions, auction/:id and supplier/:id works as intended, but login and register does not, when i click either one of them i get navigated to the correct component, the URL however changes to localhost:xxxx/login for a split second before it goes back to localhost:xxxx/previousUrl

Here is the other routerlink, that works as intended

```
<a [routerLink]="['/auction', auction.id]">
    {{category.name }} - {{auction.name}}
</a>
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser console?

Comment: Do you have any `router.navigateXxx(...)` anywhere in `LoginComponent` or `UserRegisterComponent`?

Comment: yes, turned out it was an error in my login form which somehow caused it

Answer (score 1):

When you have child routes, it's better to use the `children: []`.
This is how you use it:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: UserRegisterComponent },
  { path: 'auctions', component: AuctionListComponent, children: [
     { path: ':id', canActivate: [ AuctionDetailGuard ], component: AuctionDetailComponent },
     { path: ':id/edit', component: AuctionDetailEditComponent }
  ]},

  { path: 'supplier/:id', component: SupplierDetailComponent }
];

// This is what you can place on the item
<a [routerLink]="[idOfItem]">Link to Item</a>

// And this method you call in your component.ts file
// Add relativeTo to make it relative to the current route
// so you'll add the "edit" after the called ID.
this.router.navigate(['edit'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try login and register in the following way:

```
<a routerLink="/login">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Login
</a>
```

Comment: I get exactly the same outcome, so nothing changed

Comment: `<a routerLink="/login">` is just a shorthand for `<a [routerLink]="['/login']">`. That said, the shorthand should be preferred as the longhand syntax is disgustingly awful.